Is this a top down or bottom up recursion
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def invertTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        if not root:
            return None
        left = self.invertTree(root.left)
        right = self.invertTree(root.right)
        root.right = left
        root.left = right
        return root

I think its bottom up recursion. As we change the bottom values and proceed to root.

There is no such distinction as top-down and bottom-up recursion.

https://medium.com/cracking-the-coding-interview-in-ruby-python-and/bottom-up-and-top-down-recursion-explained-with-examples-in-ruby-javascript-and-python-mastering-9fa051ee53ff

@Shrayus but what you show as bottom up is not recursion. You can see it's not calling fib_bottom_up in fib_bottom_up. This is dynamic programming. Note that there can be "bottom up" recursion called generative recursion. But neither the article you link nor your code are that.

@Shrayus as VLAZ said, all the examples for bottom-up approach do not use recursion at all. The article is simply incorrect in calling them that.

You can also implement immutable invert as def invert(t): None if not t else TreeNode(t.val, invert(t.right), invert(t.left))

As @matszwecja stated there is no formal CS terminology for this.
However, if you are referring to these definitions of bottom-up and top-down recursion then it is bottom-up:
Bottom-up recursion: Processes from the leaves up to the root, performing main computations after reaching the base cases.
Top-down recursion: Starts processing at the root and may pass information down to child nodes before completing recursive calls.
Why?

The recursion first goes down to the leaf nodes by calling
invertTree on root.left and root.right.
At each leaf (or None node),
it starts returning back up the recursive call stack.
Once back at each node, it swaps the left and right children after completing the recursive calls on both sides.

